# Apache mod_wsgi, Django and project file permissions

Tags: django, file-permissions, mod-wsgi, apache2

I am setting up a Django project in production. But I'm dealing with a weird permission issue.
Before all, this is the structure of my project:

**project**

- **project**

  - **settings.py**
  - **urls.py**
  - **wsgi.py**
  - **...**
  - **apps**

    - app1
    - app2
    - app3
- **logs**
- **static**
- **...**

When deploying it, the site won't run unless **www-data** is user owner or group owner of **project/project/apps** (recursive) wether it's **775** or **550** permission. It has an HTTP 500 error

Weirdly, when I change permission to **777**, and remove all ownership from **www-data**, I still have the same HTTP 500 error.

The usual error is an ImportError. It cannot import some modules/apps.

Now my question is why is that? At least with permission **777**, it should run as www-data would anyway have full permissions on the folder **project/project/apps**

It looks as if Apache (**www-data**) just want to own the folder (whether it's at group level or user level)

How do you set permissions on django project folders when you deploy with Apache?

Answer (score 1):

First thing HTTP 500 error is a common error can be caused by many factor, I doubt if it is a permission issue as then it might have 403 forbidden error. Can you please add error log into the question.

Import error comes into role in python/django when your file is unable to import some other file or application. This might also cause when the working directory of a python program is incompatible with the other files imported inside the project.

Like if i have a file in src/common/libraries/a.py
and a file in src/common/helpers/a_helper.py

and in a.py
from src.common.helper.a_helper import *

When i run above a.py from mypro/src/common/libraries it will show an import error while running the same program from mypro/ directory will run the program successfully.

The Django documentation is quite useful 
read this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/